# Redrawing GIF issue with iOs webkit

Tags: ios, css, image, webkit, animated-gif

In the following example, on all the desktop browsers we tested you can see the sun beams reducing away to nothing.

In iOs, however, the beams reduce away but instead of seeing the background colour, we see a white block.

Is this a known issue? Anything I can do about it?

[Example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/207196/iOSGifTest/index.html)